# Trouble Displaying Custom Code Quality Report in Merge Requests Using VSG Tool with Self-Hosted Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm facing with displaying a custom code quality report in merge requests on GitLab.

We are running this setup on a self-hosted GitLab instance and I am using a custom tool named 'VSG' to generate a code quality report in JSON format.

The relevant part of our .gitlab-ci.yml configuration is as follows:

```
vsg:
  variables:
    KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST: "4"
    KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT: $KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST
    CODE_QUALITY_REPORT: gl-code-quality-report.json
  only:
    - main
    - merge_requests
  stage: main
  image: <MY DOCKER IMAGE>
  script:
    - cd $CI_SCRIPTS_PATH/vsg && bash run_vsg.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      codequality: $CODE_QUALITY_REPORT
```

The pipeline runs successfully, and the job logs indicate that the gl-code-quality-report.json file is found and uploaded correctly. However, the problem arises when we try to view this report in the merge requests. Despite the apparent successful upload, the code quality report is not displayed on the merge request page.

It tries to load the report but it stuck on this stage:

[image]

I checked the network accesses and realized that merge request page tries to access the link below:

https://my-repo-link/-/merge_requests/666/codequality_reports.json

But, return is always **"204 No Content"**

Anyone in the community has experienced a similar issue or has insights into what might be going wrong, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!